# Computer appears to be using wrong version of Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am consistently getting an error that occurs frequently in node version 17 or above ("error:0308010C"). I tried to fix it by downgrading to node version 16.13.0 and even typed "nvm use 16.13.0" into the terminal to use node version 16. Typing "node --version" reveals it to be 16.13.0. However, whenever I run react scripts in visual studio code, I continuously get the same error. On top of that, right below the error message, I get the text "Node.js v17.1.0". I have no idea why "npm start" and VS code insists on using node 17.1.0. Please help.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: A couple of things to try / look at: 1. Look at the `"start"` entry in `"scripts"` in your `package.json`. 2. Assuming that shows a command with `node` with no path on it, add this `"scripts"` entry: `"temp": "which node"` and then run `npm run temp` -- that tells you where it's getting `node` from, which probably has a copy of v17. 3. I don't *think* `npm start` does anything with `launch.json`, but you mentioned VS Code, so check `launch.json` to see if it has some weird path for `node`.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command : `export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`